# Memory efficient weighted set assignment with medium sized set

Tags: c++, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to match (linear assigment) two sets of elements according to some weight(i,j) function. I used munkres until now but the amount of memory used by the result alone (15000 x 15000 x sizeof(float)) is too big. My next bet would be the auction algorithm, but I'm not sure if it fits my criteria.

There may be elements which appear on one side only. An optimal and simple to implement solution is preferable. I just need a hint in the right direction, thank you very much.

Comment: The structure you describe is only 858 MB.  What's your size limitation?

Comment: I'm constrained by 32bit limits and gui parts taking memory too. Around 1gb max., but not one continuous block of memory for sure. I might be able to fit my current implementation but only with workarounds. Also, the faster the better.

Comment: Or: I prefer not to crash if the user throws a millions elements at it, just take longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a weight is calculated, it does not need to be stored with much precision.  You can immediately cut your storage requirement from 858 MB to 429 MB by using [half-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) values, or some other 16-bit format.  For example, depending on the range of weights you might want to take the logarithm of the weight and store that as a 16-bit integer.  Or you could store only the exponent part of the original 32-bit floats, which is a mere 8 bits, cutting storage down to 215 MB.

Once the weights are transformed (or quantized), you can apply the algorithm as normal.

Comment: I did that and it works... sort of. It does not crash anymore, but my implementation of Munkres is too slow to be useful. Maybe you have an idea leading me further.

Comment: You should post the code.  But if it's done according to the best published implementations then probably we won't do much better if at all.